# Removing row in Infopath form changes size and alignment of other rows

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, forms-services

I have a simple problem, but I cannot find any solution. When I remove the first row of my InfoPath layout table, it affects the alignment of every other cell in the layout table.

Before [image: (image here)]

After [image: (image here)]

The rest of the form also displays the same offset (shown by the purple arrow) throughout the entire form.

Is there a way to remove a row in my InfoPath form without it affecting the rest of the form?

Comment: This is not a solution, it's just a workaround. I remember that when I started using InfoPath 2013 a couple of years ago, tables in my opinion had a strange behaviour and sometimes a pain in the ass. Over time, I opted for: "one row = one table", so, when I put them together, it seemed to be a single table, and those weird problems (like yours) didn't happen. You may try that.

Comment: @Sergio unfortunately this form is already deployed and used daily. Recreating the form from the ground up so that one row = one table is not possible. Thank you for the insight though. On other forms in production, I have used the same technique to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is the “Initial Invoice Information” a whole one? I didn’t reproduce this issue in my InfoPath form.

Could you merge the three cells in the first row then delete it? It may resolve your issue.